# Grails 2.0 CreateCriteria private attribute cannot be queried

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-2.0

I'm trying to upgrade my app to Grails 2.0 and I face following problem. I have a private domain attribute with public getter. I'd like to query this attribute in createCriteria and it returns me: "Could not resolve property ..." exception even if the getter is public. I've seen a Jira bug http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8498?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel
but it's still not workin. Grails 1.3.7 worked fine.

My code is like:
Domain class

```
class MyClass {
   protected boolean reserved = false

   protected void setReserved(boolean reserved) {
        this.reserved = reserved
    }

   public boolean getReserved() {
        return this.reserved
    }
}
```

Query

```
def c = MyClass.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
   eq('reserved', true)
}
```

May be the problem is that 'reserved' attribute name became a reserved keyword in grails because it seems that for other attributes of different names it works...

Comment: Does it work if you remove the getter and setter (which aren't required anyway, as they do nothing more than the default as far as I can see)

Comment: The main aim of this code is to disable setting this attribute but make it available to read. I've tried to remove getters and make the attribute public but I've received lots of other problems because of complexity of the app. Nevertheless, if I'll make the attribute public I'll lose desired functionality -> hiding of the setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that to enable domain class properties being automatically persistent without having to configure them, fields must be properties, i.e. they have to have a public getter/setter pair of the same type.

Groovy does this for you when you add a public field - it makes the field private and creates a public getter and setter. But if you have a getter or setter already it doesn't do that, and if they're not both public then they're not considered a property (in the JavaBean sense) so the field isn't persistent. So it's more than that the field isn't queryable - it's not even being stored or updated in the database.

Answer (score 0):

After a few minutes of examination, I've realized that the problem is in the protected setter. If I set the setter to public, it works. It seems to be a Grails bug, and therefore I've risen grails bug, see:http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8637